# Negated character not working as expected ? ^

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I want to allow my users to enter a phone number and choose their own way of seperating the numbers (or not). So I came up with a regex:

```
var regex = /[^0-9 \/-\\\(\)\+]/;
```

In most cases it works fine, but there are some examples like `@`,`:`,`;` where it doesn't work as I would expect. Could someone give me some hint please ?

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FYtSy/1/) of what I mean

```
testvar = '123@213';
var regex = /[^0-9 \/-\\\(\)\+]/;
if(regex.test(testvar) === true) 
    { alert('Chars out of regex-range found'); } // won't fire!
```

Comment: You're saying you want them to choose how to separate it with an arbitrary combination of `-`, `+`, and `()`? So the string should only contain 0-9, +/-, and ()?

Comment: Well in other words: Any character but the specified should be forbidden: `/` `-` `\`  `()` `+` are ok!

Comment: I edited you sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/FYtSy/1/ Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a long way from `/` to `\` if you meant it. And if not, you're missing a slash before the dash:

```
var regex = /[^0-9 \/\-\\\(\)\+]/;
```

Comment: Indeed I forgot to escape the `-`. Thanks for that, just could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

A phone number only uses digits, I'd ignore the user format and just keep the digits

```
var phonenum=value.replace(/\D+/g,'');
```

Comment: Users from foreign country might enter their country code with a `+` in front of it and might get confused whats wrong with it, same with separating local numbers - it's just more user-friendly in my mind. Thanks for your words though!